# GPU benchmark for nvidia Optimus cards

Tags: gpgpu, nvidia, optimus

I need a GPGPU benchmark which will load the GPU so that I can measure the parameters like temperature rise, amount of battery drain etc. Basically I want to alert the user when the GPU is using a lot of power than normal use. Hence I need to decide on threshold values of GPU temperature, clock frequency and battery drain rate above which GPU will be using more power than normal use. I have tried using several graphics benchmark but most of them don't use GPU resources to the fullest. 
Please provide me a link to such GPGPU benchmark.

Comment: I thought when you download CUDA SDK you get samples which test your GPU's benchmarking. I even did it for my GTX285, but I dont know if Optimus cards support CUDA please check it out.

Comment: Most likely you want windows solution, but it's not specified explicitly, so I post this as comment. [SHOC](http://ft.ornl.gov/doku/shoc/start) is pretty good set of CUDA/OpenCL benchmarks, but it's for *nix only. To measure peak temperature etc, I guess, you could use any graphic benchmark, like [FurMark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/)