# non-graphics benchmarks for gpu

Tags: gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

Most of the benchmarks for gpu performance and load testing are graphics related. Is there any benchmark that is computationally intensive but not graphics related ? I am using 
DELL XPS 15 laptop, 
nvidia GT 525M graphics card,
Ubuntu 11.04 with bumblebee installed.

I want to load test my system to come up with a max load the graphics cards can handle. Are there any non-graphics benchmarks for gpu ?

Comment: **Graphics == computation**. There's a reason your fans start whirring, and that's because you're crunching a ton of matrices every second.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GPU benchmark for nvidia Optimus cards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953012/gpu-benchmark-for-nvidia-optimus-cards)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to measure?
To measure GFLOPS on the card just write a simple Kernel in Cuda (or OpenCL).
If you have never written anything in CUDA let me know and i can post something for you.
If your application is not computing intensive (take a look at a roofline paper) then I/O will be the bottleneck.  Getting data from global (card) memory to the processor takes 100's of cycles.
On the other hand if your application IS compute intensive then just time it and calculate how many bytes you process per second. In order to hit the maximum GFLOPS (your card can do 230) you need many FLOPs per memory access, so that the processors are busy and not stalling for memory and switching threads.